# Scaling Factor of Camera Projection using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, camera-projection

According to this documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

[image]

[image]

I've obtained m', A, and [R|t]. And then I want to find M'. But I have no idea to find s value, which is a scaling factor.
I only can measure distance from camera to target object using a ruler.

Please tell me how to find s value using depth information.

Comment: m' in your equation is a point in image space - pixel (2d), M' is a world point (3d). Using this equation you can only project the ray from m' and M' can be any point that lays on this ray. The s is the distance between M' and the center of projection. 
So the depth in given pixel is equivalent to s.